# Pickling game data in python, pygame

Tags: python, pygame, save, pickle

I am making a tower defence level editor using pygame and i need to be able to save the map created by the user so far if the user presses "save" button. Currently i am just trying to implement the "save" on towers since thats all the application does. So i have a list called `towers`, containing tower
objects from `Tower()` class. I tried to pickle indivisual tower objects but it didnt work.

```
towers = [Tower(), Tower()]
def save_towers(self, towers):
     with open("game_data.picle", "wb") as tower_data:
          for tower in towers:
                pickle.dump(tower, tower_data)

 if user_pressed_save():
        save_towers()
```

Then i tried pickling the whole list but that didnt work either

```
with open("game_data.picle", "wb") as tower_data:
     pickle.dump(towers, tower_data)
```

They both give the same error:

```
    pickle.dump(towers, tower_data)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'pygame.Surface' object
```

But, neither of them are pygame.Surface. What am i doing wrong? Also, please let let me know if there's a better way to do this since it's my first time making an actual program.

Edit :
Something i felt like is worth mentioning:
 The following attriburte is in tower class but i dont see how this could cause an error `self.tower = pygame.Surface((self.size)).convert()`

Comment: If you get the properties like this you could just save them to a file. ->                                     
for property, value in vars(theObject).iteritems():
    print(property,": ", value)

Comment: The `Tower` instances may not be `pygame.Surface`s, but they probably contain at least one `pygame.Surface` - in other words, one of the instance variables of the class `Tower` is a `pygame.Surface`, which cannot be pickled. I think pickling is not what you want anyway, you're better off just writing an object's desirable attributes to a JSON- or csv file or something like that. A format like that is easy to parse / read, too, when it comes time to load the objects again.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your tower class contains some reference to a pygame.Surface instance, which may not be pickled for a couple of reasons according to [the documentation for pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Whatever the case, there are some workarounds. You can convert your tower class into something that is pickable (like a dictionary) or [refer to pickle's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) on how to customize the pickling of your tower class.

Hope this helps!